# Which is more strong in business, "complain" or " claim"?

Tags: business-language

Could you explain the difference between "complain" and "claim" in business, please?

In case that I do not satisfy the ability or the capability of my business partner, which is suitable or appropriate word at the first letter or information to show my frustration?

My image is "claim" is more strong than "complain".

Comment: I think you need to give us more context...

Comment: For starters, 'claim' as a verb or noun? As @ElendilTheTall - more context is needed. You could "claim you were unhappy" or you could be "making a claim". The latter has many implications that the former doesn't. To 'make a complaint' you'd be giving a negative opinion. To 'make a claim' implies you might be undergoing some process to request what you feel is rightfully yours.

Comment: I would suggest you take help of a native English speaker to draft to the whole thing. It is not advisable to pick up individual words and form a letter this way for a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

In the limited context you've given "complain" (verb) or "complaint" (noun) is more appropriate when showing frustration. The loanword "claim" in Japanese means "complaint" in English and I'm guessing by your user name that you're thinking of the Japanese word.

For reference, here are the definitions of both "complain" and "claim."

> **Complain**
>
> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complain
>
> ---
>
> **Claim**
>
> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/claim